Unble to install Disearch tool in my Debian 12 linux Virtual OS. when trying with pip3 install dirsearch, few warnings! stopped installation process
I was trying to install these tool git clone https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch.git --depth 1  when I was trying pip3 install dirsearch there was few warnings in my terminal I'm providing code below please do have a look.
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, soupsieve, requests-toolbelt, PySocks, pycparser, psycopg-binary, ntlm_auth, mysql-connector-python, Jinja2, defusedxml, colorama, charset_normalizer, psycopg, cffi, beautifulsoup4, cryptography, pyspnego, pyopenssl, requests_ntlm
  WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/home/david/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script pyspnego-parse is installed in '/home/david/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.4 PySocks-1.7.1 beautifulsoup4-4.12.3 cffi-1.17.0 charset_normalizer-2.0.12 colorama-0.4.6 cryptography-43.0.0 defusedxml-0.7.1 mysql-connector-python-9.0.0 ntlm_auth-1.5.0 psycopg-3.2.1 psycopg-binary-3.2.1 pycparser-2.22 pyopenssl-24.2.1 pyspnego-0.11.1 requests-toolbelt-1.0.0 requests_ntlm-1.3.0 soupsieve-2.6 typing-extensions-4.12.2
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ cd dirsearch


Its nothing critical but its warning you about some scripts being installed in directory that is not in your PATH, which means you cann run the script directly from command until you provide absolute path to those script.
To resolve this, you can add your directory path /home/david/.local/bin to your PATH. Here’s how you can do it:
Open your shell configuration file (e.g., .bashrc, .zshrc, or .profile) in a text editor:
nano ~/.bashrc


Add the following line to the end of the file:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/david/.local/bin"


Apply the changes by running:
source ~/.bashrc

or you can just restart your terminal

my question is why are you cloning the repository and again installing dirsearch with your local pip3 ??

my take on that apporach:

you are basically doing one thing twice

either you can use cloned dirsearch repo or you can install with pip (which i am not sure if its available not 100% on my side)


If your goal is to run dirsearch with the cloned repo you can simply

cd into the dirsearch directory

cd dirsearch


create a venv using following command (as i see uing pip3 command python is already installed in your machine)

python -m venv venv


activate the venv

source ven/bin/activate


install the requirements text with pip

pip install -r requirements.txt


run the dirsearch and check help page

python dirsearch.py --help

you will see how you can use the disearch command with the help, just the cavet is you will have to run python dirsearch.py --<flags> but you will have advantage of keeping your local python setup clean.
Lastly, there is docker setup instruction included in the README.md file , you can setup that and have more ease of running but trade off is the resource docker container will take to run in your machine. so basically its resource trade off. maybe that will be in some other topic if you want to setup.

I followed all your steps adding the directory to nano ~/.bashrc. `# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
fi
export PATH="$PATH:/home/david/.local/bin"`     but it is still showing no such directory  even after adding.

`david@debian:~$ cd dirsearch
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ python -m venv venv
bash: python: command not found
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ `

i think you havent installed python in your local?? can you do which python or maybe its python3 -m venv venv because you have aliased python to python3 please do let me know

`david@debian:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
david@debian:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
`

ok instead of doing python -m venv venv  do python3 -m venv venv and let me know if your venv is  created or not

Again same problem.
`david@debian:~$ cd dirsearch
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ python3 -m venv venv
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ source ven/bin/activate
bash: ven/bin/activate: No such file or directory
david@debian:~/dirsearch$
`

When I was trying to create  `david@debian:~/dirsearch$ python3 -m venv venv
david@debian:~/dirsearch$
`
blank screen appearing on my terminal.

can you confirm there is venv folder inside dirsearch and please cd into venv fodler and look for bin folder and cd into it and see if there is activate
can you confirm that??
or after you activate can you do which python3

`
david@debian:~$ cd dirsearch
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ cd venv
david@debian:~/dirsearch/venv$ cd bin
david@debian:~/dirsearch/venv/bin$ cd activate
bash: cd: activate: Not a directory
david@debian:~/dirsearch/venv/bin$ activate
bash: activate: command not found
david@debian:~/dirsearch/venv/bin$
 
If I open through my home directory in graphical user interface I can clearly see there is venv folder in dirsearch as well as bin folder and also activate

ok now you need to got inside the dirsearch folder in terminal and just do source venv/bin/activate after that you should se a change in your terminal on the right side or the in the top of your  prompt. you can do which python after that you will see the path of the pythong in venv

david@debian:~/dirsearch$ source venv/bin/activate (venv) david@debian:~/dirsearch$  

now I can proceed with  pip install dirsearch ? and use dirsearch. right ?

no you now you need to do python3 dirsearch.py --help , for every command you need to use python3 dirsearch.py 

Awesome. this question can be closed as my problem resolved. now I'm running dirsearch with zero errors,  also credits should go to  -nabin sademba

it was my pleasure @david
